# Angular: How to use the directive microsyntax with cdkConnectedOverly?

Tags: angular, angular-material

According to the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax), there is a microsyntax that can be used with structural directives.

So I have some code that is working with the `cdkConnectedOverlay` directive while using the 'long hand' form:

```
  <ng-template 
    cdkConnectedOverlay 
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="savedSearchTrigger" 
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="savedSearchToggle.checked"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true" 
    [cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass]="'transparentOverlayBackdrop'">
    My overlay contents!
  </ng-template>
```

After reading about the microsyntax, it seems I should be able to shorten my code to:

```
  <ng-template 
    *cdkConnectedOverlay="origin: savedSearchTrigger; open: savedSearchToggle.checked; hasBackdrop: true; backdropClass: 'transparentOverlayBackdrop'">
     My overlay contents!
  </ng-template>
```

However, this isn't compiling. And is giving me the error `Cannot read the property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

I'm wondering if the fact I'm trying to use the microsyntax on an `ng-template` is the culprit.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular compiler expects that the microsyntax will start either with value

```
*cdkConnectedOverlay="cdkConnectedOverlayValue; otherProp: otherPropValue...."
```

or with variable:

```
*cdkConnectedOverlay="let x; otherProp: otherPropValue...."
```

Since [CdkConnectedOverlay](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/877de5691b8dd755af4a2f77b4cf57f2d374e107/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.ts#L105) doesn't have `@Input` with name `CdkConnectedOverlay` then you cannot use syntax like:

```
*cdkConnectedOverlay="1;origin: savedSearchTrigger;...
```

To work around it you could create a directive with `[cdkConnectedOverlay]` selector and the same `@Input` property but I would go with the first solution:

```
<ng-container *cdkConnectedOverlay="let x;origin: savedSearchTrigger; open: opened; 
                 hasBackdrop: true; backdropClass: 'transparentOverlayBackdrop'">
```

Despite the fact that it will compile you can notice that your content is not displayed. To fix it you should use `<ng-container *cdkConnectedOverlay` instead of `<ng-template *cdkConnectedOverlay` so that `My overlay contents!` content won't be wrapped in additional `ng-template`

Finally, take a look at [**Ng-run Example**](https://ng-run.com/edit/97ReK0VhXaLq1TnjTVVl?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update**

Note, that sugar `(*)` syntax does not support `@Output` therefore the event won't be fired in the following code:

```
<ng-container *cdkConnectedOverlay="..." (backdropClick)="opened = false">
```

To work around it you could pass some handler as `@Input` by creating additional directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClick]'
})
export class ConnectedOverlayBackdropClick {
  @Input('cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClick') backDropHandler: Function;

  @HostListener('backdropClick')
  backdropClick() {
    this.backDropHandler();
  }
}
```

And then catch event in component:

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *cdkConnectedOverlay="let item; origin: savedSearchTrigger; open: opened; 
hasBackdrop: true; backdropClass: 'transparentOverlayBackdrop'; backdropClick: close">
```

**component.ts**

```
close = () => {
  this.opened = false;
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/uNxxdBQSCjvnsdZgzCTE)**

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great explanation and feedback. I almost got it working perfectly, but for some reason events aren't properly emitted like `(backdropClick)="opened = false"`. See https://ng-run.com/edit/vTwokbMJXwwJLS6phwOt

Comment: Thanks for adding the `@Output`, it really helped me learn more about how Angular works.